Is there a way to upload instructional videos that will get embedded the way images get embedded?
Is there a method to embed an instructional video clip in a Q&A the way this can be done with images? Basically what I am asking is whether there is a dedicated space to upload such stuff to similar to how the default image embedding ends up on imgur.

Embedding videos is enabled on a per-site basis. They are enabled for Gaming.SE (example) and Music.SE. Only Youtube videos are embedded. 
If you think this will benefit the site, post a feature-request. 

okay, thanks. Good to know it is possible. But since this is obviously via Youtube I am skeptical. Besides I don't have a video ready just yet, but I was wondering whether this is possible in general. Thanks.
